# Past Username Registry

Tags: discussion

It's a simple fact that since Stack Exchange allows us to change our usernames, we do so occasionally. While I support this practice, it can be annoying on occasion, as it can confuse others and leaves apparently broken comments.

With that in mind, I am hereby creating a registry of past usernames.

To add an entry, please answer this question in the following format:

**<Current username>**

- <Most recent past username>
- <Second most recent past username>
- <Etc.>

**If you can't remember one or more of your past usernames, that's perfectly all right; just list the ones you remember.**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not what Meta is for and NOT a discussion

Comment: (a) As a self-supported effort, I suspect you'll have pretty much no one but yourself list a name. (b) Meta questions cannot be pinned, so this question will vanish into the depths of history. (c) In over 3 years of participation, I've not had a single reason to search for this kind of data. (d) If it does leave broken comments, that would be valuable to post on [meta.se] so it can be addressed programmatically.

Comment: Let's not forget that comments aren't supposed to be permanent.

Comment: @sphennings that upsets both my inner Nietzsche and Glarnak something awful.

Answer (score 7):

If I would be puzzled by how somebody is or were called before, my first try would be to look at their profile for clues, not on Meta.

Therefore it makes more sense, if you want to keep track of your aliases, to add them to your profile, something like

> Previously known as: ....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Handy *especially* with all the "XYZ Monica" type user names floating around. Case in point, L. Dutch! But at least you kept the recognisable part of your name. I've seen some names like "SE Quit Firing the Good Ones" or something like that. I'd have no idea who that person actually is!

Comment: @elemtilas also have no idea who that guy actually is

Answer (score 0):

**The Daleks**

- Marvin the Paranoid Android
- Thescribe11 (or just Thescribe; I can't remember which)